# Query wont return anything but a list

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr

I have been using R to query a table on a database running SQL server successfully using `dbGetQuery`. I am trying to query a different table and was getting no where because of errors. I decided to try and just use Dplyr. I've read multiple guides and I am at a complete loss.

I am trying to query a small table just as a test. Here is my code

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), Driver = "SQL Server", Server = "server address", 
             database = "database") 
df <- tbl(con, "doctor")
```

It returns a list of 2 rather than a table. Could someone point me in some kind of direction. I'm guessing there is something I don't understand about R or Sql.

Edit: Here is some information about the output of the above code

```
>  class(df)
[1] "tbl_dbi"  "tbl_sql"  "tbl_lazy" "tbl"
```

#

The adding collect

```
df <- tbl(con, "doctor") %>%
  collect
```

does solve the problem. Here is information after running it with collect

```
> class(df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

After reading the vignette on collect I understand what it does in this case. I still don't understand why in the guides they don't need to use collect.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible minimal example and your expected output; for example how/where do you define `con`? I assume you're using `dbplyr` to connect to your database?

Comment: con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 Driver = "SQL Server",
                 Server = "server address",
                 database = "database")

Comment: *"It returns a list of 2 rather than a table"* How does `df` look like? "A list of 2" what? Does a remote table "doctor" exist? Please understand that we don't know anything about your database, so you need to provide specifics! Also [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51092343/edit) your question to include additional (code) details rather than posting as comments.

Comment: `df <- tbl(con, "doctor") %>% collect` will give you the `data.frame`. Before collect you're on server side and your object is basically a wrapper around the sql query to run on the server.